# Assign values in a new column based on other columns (multiple matches with merge)

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

There are two dataframes, as per the example below, that I would like to assign values to the second dataframe based on two columns (Product and Price). However, important to highlight, that there are same products and price in different Stores/Sellers.

Please find a simple example below.

1st df

```
df = {'Product':['TV', 'iPhone', 'TV'], 'Seller': ['Pankaj', 'John', 'John'] , 'Amount': [15, 10, 20], 'Price' : [2.50, 3.50, 2.5], 'Store': ['Walmart', 'Amazon', 'Amazon']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

2nd df

```
df2 = {'Product':['TV', 'TV', 'iPhone', 'iPhone', 'TV'], 'Amount': [10, 5, 5, 5, 20], 'Price' : [2.50, 2.5, 3.50, 3.50, 2.5], 'ID':['GLOBAL', 'FLAGSHIP', 'GREEN', 'FLAGSHIP', 'GLOBAL']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

Expected Result:

```
df2 = {'Product':['TV', 'TV', 'iPhone', 'iPhone', 'TV'], 'Amount': [10, 5, 5, 5, 20], 'Price' : [2.50, 2.5, 3.50, 3.50, 2.5], 'ID':['GLOBAL', 'FLAGSHIP', 'GREEN', 'FLAGSHIP', 'GLOBAL'], 'Store': ['Walmart', 'Walmart', 'Amazon', 'Amazon', 'Amazon'], 'Seller': ['Pankaj', 'Pankaj', 'John', 'John', 'John']}
```

I tried to split quantities in one unit on both dataframes and then merge based on columns values. However, dind't work as expected. My guess is that the outcome is incorrect since there are conditions that match with more than one line. Therefore, the possible solution might be looping over the two dataframes matching columns that have the same details and removing the matched amounts from the original dataframe.

What I tried:

```
df= df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Amount'])].reset_index(drop=True)
df['Amount'] = 1

df2= df2.loc[df2.index.repeat(df2['Amount'])].reset_index(drop=True)
df2['Amount'] = 1

df2 = df2.merge(df, how='left', left_on=['Product', 'Price'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to merge dataframes but your df1 and df2 are still dictionnaries.
Begin by converting them to dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

You can then drop columns on your first dataframe and don't forget to include which column to merge on in the second dataframe

```
df.drop(columns=['Amount', 'Price'])
df3 = df2.merge(df, how='left', left_on=['Product','Price'],right_on=['Product','Price'])
df3

  Product  Amount_x  Price        ID  Seller  Amount_y    Store
0      TV        10    2.5    GLOBAL  Pankaj        15  Walmart
1      TV        10    2.5    GLOBAL    John        20   Amazon
2      TV         5    2.5  FLAGSHIP  Pankaj        15  Walmart
3      TV         5    2.5  FLAGSHIP    John        20   Amazon
4  iPhone         5    3.5     GREEN    John        10   Amazon
5  iPhone         5    3.5  FLAGSHIP    John        10   Amazon
6      TV        20    2.5    GLOBAL  Pankaj        15  Walmart
7      TV        20    2.5    GLOBAL    John        20   Amazon
```

Let me know if that works for you

Comment: No, the issue persists. If you take a closer look to your dataframe. The total quantity of each product by seller, by store doesn't match with the original information. 
On both dataframes, the quantity are matched . What I'm trying to is add new information to the second dataframe.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you wish to add information to your df2. It seems that the only way to diffeciate products is via amounts in your expected df. Also, why would you want your merge keys to be both Product and Price since the price is always the same?

Comment: Price can be different, this is a simplified example. 
This process works with amounts that varies from 1 to 10,000 and price can be the same or not. When prices are different is quite easy to differentiate. The problem is when u have different amounts, same prices and same products. 

That's the reason that I splited the dataframe in one unit by row. I attempted to match each row individually and get the additional data that I need (Store/Seller)